# Attask API Username Search Case Sensitive

Tags: c#, api, attask

I'm currently trying to use Attask API's to pull out a list of users based on a string parameter, using the name_Mod "contains".

So far so good, I can pull back a list of usernames and their corresponding ID's but I've found that the api appears to be case sensitive.

For example, I give it the parameter "Dan"...

"https://wibble.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/user/search?sessionID=wibble&$$LIMIT=2000&name=Dan&name_Mod=contains&fields=ID,name"

...and I get results like "Daniel Brown"

I give it "dan"...

"https://wibble.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/user/search?sessionID=wibble&$$LIMIT=2000&name=dan&name_Mod=contains&fields=ID,name"

...I get results like "Rachael Jordan", but no "Daniel Brown".

Is there a way to tell Attask that I don't care about case sensitivity? To just give me both results and let me worry about it? Or a way around this particular limitation if it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also other `MOD` named `cicontains` where `ci` means `case insensitive`. You can use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a few limitations with the method Jim used.

Specifically, this query will not work as you expect.

..attask/api/project/search?status=CPL&status=CON&status_Mod=contains&$$LIMIT=2000

Only the first status is returned.

My preferred solution for searching with a "Contains" filter is this:

../attask/api/user/search?filters={firstName:['Chris','Steve','steve','Stephen','Anne']}

I feel it is easier to assemble an array programmatically as you do not have to prepend the field name.

If needed you could perform a ToUpper, ToLower and Case the first Char in the string and cover most of the

The filters verb does not respond to the field Modifier. You cannot use Not Equal, Less Than, Etc.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

You are correct search fields are case sensitive. The only way you can get both results, dan and Dan, is by including both in the rest request. An example would be

"https://wibble.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/user/search?sessionID=wibble&$$LIMIT=2000&name=dan&name=Dan&name_Mod=contains&fields=ID,name"

Let me know if that works for you.