# AtTask Ordering the Results in a Report Query in the API

Tags: php, api, attask

I am doing a "report" query through the AtTask API. Using the guidance from [here](https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Report). However, I'm grouping by a date field in the custom data. ('DE:project:Actual Completion Month_1_GroupBy'). However the results come back unordered. As I'm going to iterate through the results now to make a chart. I'd like to order the list. Is there a parameter that you submit in the query to specify the sorting order of the grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"DE:project:Actual Completion Month_1_Sort" => "asc"

Answer (score 1):

As [Craig mentioned earlier](http://blueagave.pl) you can use `<< field_name >>_Sort` parameter.

Please note that if your sort by string field, you will get case sensitive results:

- Test C
- Untitled Project
- cache test 2

and not:

- cache test 2
- Test C
- Untitled Project

If you need to sort by string and get case insensitive results, use ciasc (or cidesc):

```
/project/search&method=GET&status=CUR&name_Sort=ciasc&fields=name
```

Credits: [Blue Agave](http://blueagave.pl) and [Hamlet Hakobyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25413831/4073877)