# AtTask API order by date?

Tags: api, sql-order-by, attask

I've gone around in circles on the web trying to find any relevant information, including the API Docs, for ordering results by ASC/DESC order...

/task/search?name=NAME HERE&percentComplete=0&fields=plannedCompletionDate,project:status,project:name,project:plannedCompletionDate

I want to be able to have my results ordered by plannedCompletionDate instead of having to do it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by adding 
plannedCompletionDate_Sort=asc
so your call would be

```
/task/search?name=NAME HERE&percentComplete=0&fields=plannedCompletionDate,project:status,project:name,project:plannedCompletionDate&plannedCompletionDate_Sort=asc
```

Comment: It simply blows my mind with how detailed of an API AtTask has, they can't  document something as simple, yet as powerful, as ordering..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort by string (i.e. project name) you can also use `name_Sort=ciasc` to get case insensitive results:

```
/project/search&method=GET&status=CUR&name_Sort=ciasc&fields=name
```

Credits: [Blue Agave](http://blueagave.pl) and [Hamlet Hakobyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25413831/4073877)